# Loading Sound gives exception on Sound.id3

Tags: apache-flex, exception, audio

When loading a MP3 to a `flash.media.Sound` object the id3 property gives an error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.
```

Offcourse, like many errors in Flex, the Flex documentation doesn't mention a thing about this, except that it exists...

The MP3 is valid (i've checked it with MediaPlayer and iTunes), the Sound object is in a good state (`bytesTotal` and `bytesLoaded` both reflect the correct amount of bytes).

Has anyone had this problem too? Any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: Loading the sound from same domain or different?

Comment: From the local filesystem (i'm using -use-network=false to avoid sandbox security)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MP3 should be fine.

If you want to access more data about your mp3 file, rather than just play, you will need a policy file that allows it. Similar to loading an image, if you just add it to the display it and don't access the pixels, it's all good, but if you want to access the pixels you should have permission(a crossdomain xml).

For images, when you call the load image, you can pass a LoaderContext in which you explicitly say you want to check for a crossdomain.xml file and get access to the content.

Similarly you should create a [SoundLoaderContext](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/SoundLoaderContext.html#SoundLoaderContext%28%29) with the **second** parameter set to true(to check) and use that in the sound load call.

e.g.

```
var snd:Sound = new Sound();
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourSound.mp3");
            var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(0, true);

            snd.load(req, context);
            snd.play();
```

For ID3 data you should listen for the ID3 event:

```
sound.addEventListener(Event.ID3, onID3);

function onID3(event:Event) {
    for(var i in sound.id3)
        trace('prop: ' + i + ' value: '  + sound.id3[i]);
}
```

For more info, you might find the [mp3infoutil library](http://code.google.com/p/mp3infoutil/) handy.

HTH,
George

Comment: This helps me get rid of the error, but returns a ID3Info object with everything null, even when all bytes are loaded and the "complete"-event is dispatched... Now what? Edit: tried again with another mp3, gives me the correct id3info... Perhaps Id3v2 which results in null?